# Shared view model in android compose project while using Hilt for dependency injection?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, android-mvvm

Anyone has any clue how to retain a shared view model object across different composables?
I'm using hilt and injecting viewmodel instance using hilt in composable.
Basically there are 3 screens which share same data and changes I want to share it and I'm thinking of sharing this data through a shared view model.

```
myViewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()
```

So how can i use this MyViewModel as shared view model?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70342880/3585796) answer your question?

Comment: @PylypDukhov thank you so much buddy for the help.. this answer was super helpful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you need is something like this to find the view model in your navigation back stack entry and pass it to next composable screen:

```kotlin
val backStackEntry = remember {
    navHostController.getBackStackEntry("first_screen_route_where_viewmodel_was_firstly_initialized")
}
val viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel(backStackEntry)
```

Now you have got the view model which is exactly at same state where you have left it in previous screens.
Now you can use it as a shared view model.
Thanks @Pylyp for guidance..

Comment: Note that 
`remember {navController.getBackStackEntry(parentId)}` can cause crashes and now triggers a lint warning ([more here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227382831)). 
  
 the solution is to use a the `backStackEntry` as a key to `remember` such as.    
    

`remember(navBackStackEntry) {navController.getBackStackEntry(parentId)}`

Answer (score 5):

As per the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation):

> If you need to retrieve the instance of a ViewModel scoped to
> navigation routes or the navigation graph instead, use the
> hiltViewModel composable function and pass the corresponding
> backStackEntry as a parameter:

```kotlin
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel
import androidx.navigation.compose.getBackStackEntry

@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = startRoute) {
        navigation(startDestination = innerStartRoute, route = "Parent") {
            // ...
            composable("exampleWithRoute") { backStackEntry ->
                val parentEntry = remember(backStackEntry) {
                    navController.getBackStackEntry("Parent")
                }
                val parentViewModel = hiltViewModel<ParentViewModel>(parentEntry)
                ExampleWithRouteScreen(parentViewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to @gabhor's answer you can create an extension function to avoid writing the same code everywhere.

```kotlin
@Composable
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> NavBackStackEntry.sharedViewModel(navController: NavController): T {
    val navGraphRoute = destination.parent?.route ?: return hiltViewModel()
    val parentEntry = remember(this) {
        navController.getBackStackEntry(navGraphRoute)
    }

    return hiltViewModel(parentEntry)
}
```

Reference: https://github.dev/philipplackner/NestedNavigationGraphsGuide