# Jetpack Compose - SnapshotStateList<T>.clear() of a ViewModel does not worl after a switch to another screen - Error: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Currently i am trying to lern Jetpack Compose. For one part of the App I want to use oen ViewModel for multiple Screens. But the problem described below occures.

I have the following ViewModel:

```
class NewRoomViewModel : ViewModel() {
   
    
    private val _floorPlan = mutableStateListOf<FloorPlanWall>()
    var floorPlan: SnapshotStateList<FloorPlanWall> = _floorPlan

    /* ... */
```

In the first screen new elements are added to the list.
In the next screen I want to call `newRoomViewModel.floorplan.clear()`, but I get the following error: `java.util.NoSuchElementException`

Both screen fragments access the same instance of the obeject. It is decleared as

```
private val newRoomViewModel : NewRoomViewModel by viewModels()
```

in the `MainActivity` and passed via the NavGraph to the fragments.
It is also possible to delet single Elements of the list.

PS: Sorry for my bad englisch and if my problem is unclear. I can provide more code.

I tried ti find the source of the problem and the only thing I can say certain is that the list cant be cleared after navigating to the next Screen.

For more context my NavGraph look like this:

```
@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(navController: NavHostController, newRoomViewModel : NewRoomViewModel){
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Start.route
    ){
        /* ... */

        composable(
            route = Screen.NewRoom2.route
        ){
            NewRoom2Fragment(navController = navController, newRoomViewModel = newRoomViewModel)
        }
        composable(
            route = Screen.NewRoom3.route
        ){
            NewRoom3Fragment(navController = navController, newRoomViewModel = newRoomViewModel)
        }
       
    }
}
```

And the screen switch looks like this:

```
navController.navigate(route = Screen.NewRoom3.route)
```

Comment: Compose navigation creates new modelStoreOwner for each destination. Maybe this will help [ViewModel with compose navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002018/why-a-new-viewmodel-is-created-in-each-compose-navigation-route)

Comment: @pushpull I have already tryed this and it did not work